# Is AAPL on both NYSE and NASDAQ?

Tags: equities, nasdaq, nyse

https://www.nyse.com/listings_directory/stock

I can find AAPL on the above page.

But I can also see it on NASDAQ.

https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/

Yahoo says `NasdaqGS`. So I'd assume that it is only on NASDAQ. Then I am confused on why it is still on NYSE.

How to just get the NYSE stocks from the NYSE website?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the first list is just NYSE listed stocks, it has MSFT too.
Anyways AAPL is NASDAQ listed.

Comment: How to get NYSE-listed stocks?

Comment: https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNGS:AAPL it is common to trade on several exchanges.

Comment: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener
 has a filter for nyse stocks for example.

Comment: It's a custom to accept the answer if addresses your question :)